# Setting up Access Token Middleware in React when using a hook/context provider for your token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-query

tl;dr:
How does one go about setting up a hook to handle token headers across axios api calls in a meaningfully maintainable way, with the assumption that the token itself is exposed as a hook.

I am currently handling authentication by exposing an access token/permissions in a context, and providing a protected route implementation that conditionally exposes the outlet OR a navigation call based on whether the token exists (which is retrieved from the hook).

Initially this works alright, and every component/hook in my application will have access to the hook to get the token. However, what I really want to do now is gain access to that hook where I make my api calls to set up an axios interceptor to manage the auth header for my api calls.

The issue I'm running into is I think any api call will have to be nested within a hook in order for me to use the token on it, and I'm not really sure what that looks like.
I'm using react-query, and was hoping I'd be able to use a mutation to set something to be accessed throughout the app, but that suffers the same pitfall of needing a component to be able to access the hook.

Is it possible to implement a hook for your token - appending middleware with axios?

```
the protected route implementation:
import React from 'react';
import { Outlet, useLocation, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from './AuthProvider';

const ProtectedRouterOutlet = () => {
  const { token } = useAuth();
  const location = useLocation();
  if (!token) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
  }
  return <Outlet/>;
};

export default ProtectedRouterOutlet;
```

Auth provider context wrapper

```
 const AuthContext = React.createContext<any>(null);

export const useAuth = () => {
  return React.useContext(AuthContext);
};

const loginApiCall = (userName: string, password: string) =>{
    if(!userName || !password) { return Promise.reject('Missing Credentials') }
    return axios.post(`${auth_service}/oauth/token`, {username: userName, password: password})
  }
  

const AuthProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [token, setToken] = React.useState<string | null>(null);
    const location = useLocation();
    useEffect(() => {
      if(location.pathname === '/login' && token) {
        navigate('/');
      } else if (!token) {
        navigate('/login');
      }
    }, [token])
  


const loginCall = useMutation( (data: any) => loginApiCall(data.username, data.password), {onSuccess: token => {
    console.log('success', token);
    setToken(token.data);
    // I could do a settimeout here Or use the useeffect hook
    // setTimeout(() => navigate('/'))
  }})

const handleLogin = async (username: string, password: string) => {
  loginCall.mutate({username, password});
};

const handleLogout = () => {
  setToken(null);
  // todo: call logout api to invalidate token
};

const value = useMemo(() => ({
  token,
  onLogin: handleLogin,
  onLogout: handleLogout,
}), [token]);

return (
  <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
    {children}
  </AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

};

export default AuthProvider;

and the main app file:

```
const rootComponent = () => {
return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <AuthProvider>
         <Shell>
            <Outlet/>
         </Shell>
      </AuthProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};
```

EDIT:
I found this (setting defaults in axios), but I'm not sold on it yet:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(token) { // setting default common header if token exists
      axios.defaults.headers.common = {...axios.defaults.headers.common, Authorization: `Bearer ${token.access_token}`};
    }
    if(location.pathname === '/login' && token) {
      navigate('/');
    } else if (!token) {
      navigate('/login');
    }
  }, [token])
```

Comment: It was unclear what/where exactly you were wanting/needing help with (*i.e. is this a react-router question, a React hooks question, a react-query question, axios? etc....*), but your edit to set a default header is a solution I've used and works well. Just keep in mind that as the token in state changes, i.e. is invalidated, that you'll want to then remove that common header.

Comment: I'm bushwhacking through unfamiliar territory with some of this, and was looking for some input from some others who have done this before. 
I also found out I should maintain other headers, ie:
axios.defaults.headers.common = {...axios.defaults.headers.common, 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.access_token}`};

quick question though, how do you go about removing the common header?

Comment: Since I don't know exactly what headers I may have I just kind of want to keep everything BUT auth, (though thinking through it, maybe a remaining auth header isn't bad if the backend rejects it anyways)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that after I said that, that maybe you just always set the default authorization header when the token is defined in state and let the backend validate it and return error if it's invalid. As for other headers, check the [config order of precedence](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-order-of-precedence), basically axios request config arguments are merged into instance defaults, merged into global defaults, merged into base defaults.